# Powershell Array to csv

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, export-csv

I'm pretty new to powershell and I cant figure out how to get my array into a csv file, where each string goes onto a new row. Below is some example code.

```
$ServerList = "E:\Coding Projects\Powershell\ServerNameList.txt"
$ServerNames = Get-content $ServerList
write-host $ServerNames
$OutputPath = "E:\Coding Projects\Powershell\Output.csv"

$Names = @() 
$Outcome = @()
foreach ($Server in $ServerNames){
    $Names += $Server 
    if ($Server -match "Joe"){
        $Outcome += "pass" 
       
    }else{
        $Outcome += "Fail" 
    }

}
$Names
$Outcome

$csv = New-object psobject -property @{ 
    'User' = $Names -join ',' 
    'Groups' = $Outcome -join ','
    }

write-host $csv

$csv | Select-Object -property User, Groups | Export-csv -path $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation
```

When I check the csv file, all of the outputs appear on one row instead of iterating down the rowin its specific column.
Any help would be very useful and appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're creating 2 separate arrays of string values - instead, you'll want to create a single array of objects with two properties:

```
$ServerList = "E:\Coding Projects\Powershell\ServerNameList.txt"
$ServerNames = Get-content $ServerList
write-host $ServerNames
$OutputPath = "E:\Coding Projects\Powershell\Output.csv"

$serversWithOutcome = @()
foreach ($Server in $ServerNames){
    $serversWithOutcome += [pscustomobject]@{
        User = $Server 
        Groups = $Server -match "Joe" 
    }
}

$serversWithOutcome | Export-csv -path $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks. This is so much simpler than i expected it to be!

Comment: Possible improvement: `$serversWithOutcome = foreach ...` and remove `$serversWithOutcome +=`. PowerShell automatically creates an array when output of `foreach` is assigned to a variable like this. Internally PowerShell uses a more efficent method than `+=`, which recreates the array to accomodate the size for every new item.

Comment: @zett42 Absolutely! There's a reason I stuck with OP's use of `+=` here though - "Servers" is the kind of thing we count in 10s, or 100s, maybe 1000s if you're in a big environment - but it's not the kind of thing we count _in millions_ - in other words, _it doesn't really matter_ :-)